# How to recover Hard Bricked Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7

I have hard bricked my Nexus 7 tablet by fault while flashing. Now it's not turning on in any mode. Is there any chance to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a usb jig
Download Odin(Just search it on google)

Download a firmware for your device. 
Google https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en
Samsung http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/

connect the usb jig to your device
Your device will boot into fastboot mode
Remove the jig
connect your device to PC
Start Odin
click on PDA and select the .tar file
click on start
wait till it completes(Takes 5 to 15 mins)
device will reboot

You will have your phone working.

NOTE: Make sure that you have drivers of your device installed on your PC.

Comment: Thanks Omkar, But while searching for usb jig on google I found that these are only for Samsung devices and I have ASUS Nexus 7 Tablet. Please let me know if I am wrong. I only want to get into fastboot mode, where I can flash appropriate image.